# Stripping and testing against Month component of a date

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-04-13','2017-05-14','2017-05-15','2017-06-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date'])
print df
```

I would like to pass in a date parameter as a string as follows:

```
date = '2017-03-22'
```

I would now like to know if there are any dates in my DataFrame 'df' for which the month is 3 months after the month in the date parameter.

That is if the month in the date parameter is March, then it should check if there are any dates in df from June. If there are any, I would like to see those dates. If not, it should just output 'No date found'.

In this example, the output should be '2017-06-01' as it is a date from June as my date parameter is from March.

Could anyone help how may I get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

convert your column to `Timestamp`

```
df.Series_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Series_Date)

date = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-01')
```

Then

```
df[
    (df.Series_Date.dt.year - date.year) * 12 +
     df.Series_Date.dt.month - date.month == 3
]

  Series_Date
4  2017-06-01
```